# Ask for User camera access only Once

Tags: javascript, getusermedia

I need acces to the user webcam so that he can do en an experience on the website i'm developing. At some point he can restart the experience, but he has to accept the use of his webcam again.

Is it possible to get the access to the webcam once he accepted at the first time ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Chrome`, when a page's media request is granted, it will be stored automatically only if it is a `SSL/TLS` connection.

In `FireFox`, if the connection is `SSL/TLS`, the end user has an option to select for `Always Share`. It can be found in the drop down menu accessed from hitting the arrow next to the allow button.

Either way, it must be `HTTPS` for the user to accept once and never again.